# pywinauto ribbon menu returns no control identifiers

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate a series of tasks I have to do with a given software. I've managed to "wing it" using keyboard controls, but to extend the complexity of the script I need to access a ribbon menu.

So far, my code is as follows:

```
windows = pwa.Desktop(backend="win32").windows()
running_windows = [window.window_text() for window in windows]

midas_title = ""
target_title = "Civil"

for window in running_windows:
    if target_title in window:
        midas_title += window
    else:
        pass

app = pwa.Application().connect(title=midas_title)
app[midas_title].set_focus()

app.MidasGenMainFrmClass['MIDAS/Civil'].print_control_identifiers()
app.MidasGenMainFrmClass['BCGPRibbonBar:40000000:8:10003:10'].print_control_identifiers()
```

Judging by the top/left and bottom/right coordinates of the `BCGPRibbonBar:40000000:8:10003:10`, that seems to be the menu that I want to access so that I can click on the "Results" button in this ribbon (my final goal), but when I do `print_control_identifiers()` on that the output I get is this:

```
BCGPRibbonBar:40000000:8:10003:10 - 'MIDAS/Civil'    (L0, T0, R1920, B174)
['MIDAS/CivilBCGPRibbonBar:40000000:8:10003:10', 'BCGPRibbonBar:40000000:8:10003:10', 'MIDAS/Civil']
child_window(title="MIDAS/Civil", class_name="BCGPRibbonBar:40000000:8:10003:10")
```

I'm very new to this, but seems like the ribbon has no children?

[Seems like I'm too new to embed images, but link here to what the ribbon menu looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bISeD.png)

[And finally, link to the image of the inspector of the "Results" menu where I'd like to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICs5k.png)

Hopefully this is sufficient information, but please let me know if anything is missing.

If anyone has any idea of what I might be doing wrong, that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `backend="uia"` instead of `backend="win32"`. Ribbon controls are visible to UIA backend only. `Application(backend="uia")` is also a must.

Comment: When i use ```Application(backend="uia")```, I get the following error ```pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError``` and ```pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'Civil 2020 - [path_to_file_location ' in 'dict_keys([])'```
With ```backend="win32"``` the application runs successfully.

Comment: You also need this for `Application(backend="uia").connect(...)`. Please edit your question with new error details. It's not clear which line exactly failed.